# Set http_proxy for Docker parent image build

Tags: docker, http-proxy

I'm running Docker on a machine that relies on an internal proxy for all internet access.

I'd like to base my image on `pointslope/datomic-pro-starter:0.9.5130`
which uses [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/pointslope/docker-datomic/blob/master/Dockerfile).

It uses `curl` during `ONBUILD`. How do I set http_proxy at that level? I tried `ENV` and `ARG` but I don't think that's meant for parent images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Docker can support this currently.

The `Dockerfile` is plain text, I will recommend to re-write the `Dockerfile` from beginning, which you can insert proxy servers on the top.

Comment: I had tried this but it wasn't working. It would hang on the `curl` statement. Not sure if it's been built or not, but it was my impression that `ONBUILD` runs when the child image is actually built.

Comment: ic, in this case, you have to re-write the Dockerfile from beginning and build it in your environment.

Comment: Ok. I think I'll switch strategies and build outside of the firewalled environment to avoid this.